OrientationBuilder not updating UI when switching LandScape to portrait mode and from portrait to landScape
I’m using OrientationBuilder in my Flutter app to change the UI based on the orientation. However, when I switch back to portrait mode, the UI of the landscape mode is still showing. Here is my code:
OrientationBuilder(
  builder: (context, orientation) {
    bool isLandscape = orientation == Orientation.landscape;
    return Padding(
      padding: isLandscape
          ? EdgeInsets.only(
              left: ResponsiveFunctions.responsiveWidth(10),
              top: ResponsiveFunctions.responsiveHeight(52),
              right: ResponsiveFunctions.responsiveWidth(10),
              bottom: ResponsiveFunctions.responsiveHeight(3))
          : EdgeInsets.only(
              left: ResponsiveFunctions.responsiveWidth(16),
              top: ResponsiveFunctions.responsiveHeight(42),
              right: ResponsiveFunctions.responsiveWidth(16),
              bottom: ResponsiveFunctions.responsiveHeight(10)),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Column(
                // Additional widgets here
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  },
);

I’ve used OrientationBuilder to change the UI according to the landscape mode and portrait, but when I switch back to the normal screen, the UI of the landscape mode is still showing. How can I ensure that the UI updates correctly when switching landscape to portrait mode and portrait to landscape?

First, make sure the parent widget you are using is not preceded by a const.
Second, the problem may be from ResponsiveFunctions.responsiveWidth(10), if it is returning values that are orientation dependent but from outside the build tree or not updating correctly since height and with are inverted when changing orientations.
With little code provided, it is hard to pinpoint the issue!

normal screen is portrait.
